Exception in plugin MapStruct Support (1.7.0) IntelliJ IDEA
I have spent several hours trying to resolve this IDE the following IDE error(I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1 (Community Edition)), but I have not been able to resolve it:
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot create class org.mapstruct.intellij.inspection.WrongUsageOfMappersFactoryInspection (classloader=PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=MapStruct Support, id=org.mapstruct.intellij, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1/plugins/mapstruct-intellij-1.7.0.jar, version=1.7.0, package=null, isBundled=false), packagePrefix=null, state=active))
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doInstantiateClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:926)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:902)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:943)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.LazyExtensionInstance.createInstance(LazyExtensionInstance.java:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.CustomLoadingExtensionPointBean.createInstance(CustomLoadingExtensionPointBean.java:28)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEP.instantiateTool(InspectionEP.java:223)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionToolWrapper.getTool(InspectionToolWrapper.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionToolWrapper.getGroupDisplayName(InspectionToolWrapper.java:151)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.ToolOptionDescription.<init>(ToolOptionDescription.java:20)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.InspectionsTopHitProvider.getOptions(InspectionsTopHitProvider.java:29)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.TopHitCache$getCachedOptions$1.invoke(TopHitCache.kt:61)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.TopHitCache$getCachedOptions$1.invoke(TopHitCache.kt:48)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.TopHitCache.getCachedOptions$lambda$0(TopHitCache.kt:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.TopHitCache.getCachedOptions(TopHitCache.kt:48)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProviderActivity$execute$2.invokeSuspend(OptionsTopHitProvider.kt:165)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProviderActivity$execute$2.invoke(OptionsTopHitProvider.kt)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProviderActivity$execute$2.invoke(OptionsTopHitProvider.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span(tracer.kt:56)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span$default(tracer.kt:49)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProviderActivity.execute(OptionsTopHitProvider.kt:144)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProviderActivity$execute$1.invokeSuspend(OptionsTopHitProvider.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mapstruct/Mapper
    at org.mapstruct.intellij.util.MapstructUtil.<clinit>(MapstructUtil.java:78)
    at org.mapstruct.intellij.inspection.WrongUsageOfMappersFactoryInspection.<clinit>(WrongUsageOfMappersFactoryInspection.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.allocateInstance(DirectMethodHandle.java:520)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.findConstructorAndInstantiateClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:908)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doInstantiateClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:917)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mapstruct.Mapper PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=MapStruct Support, id=org.mapstruct.intellij, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1/plugins/mapstruct-intellij-1.7.0.jar, version=1.7.0, package=null, isBundled=false), packagePrefix=null, state=active)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.kt:156)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 36 more

My pom.xml looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>name</name>
    <description>A new way to manage to beauty time</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <!-- automatically run annotation processors within the incremental compilation -->
        <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0.2594</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.maps/google-maps-services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.hypersistence/hypersistence-tsid -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hypersistence-tsid</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
       
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.30</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

any ideas? Many Thanks!

This is a 3rd party plugin, similar ask is found from its issue tracker, please follow up here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/3328
